# Convert existing THREE.js Materials to CubeTexture for use as an envMap

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to conert existing materials to a CubeTexture? I would like to use this later for an envMap of a GLTF Model. I know there is a CubicTextureLoader but I want to use the existing materials.

```
var testMateri1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-r.jpg')} );
var testMateri2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-l.jpg')} );
var testMateri3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-t.jpg')} );
var testMateri4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-d.jpg')} );
var testMateri5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-f.jpg')} );
var testMateri6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: new THREE.TextureLoader(ladeManager).load('textures/face-b.jpg')} );
var meinEnvMap = new THREE.CubeTexture( [testMateri1, testMateri2, testMateri3, testMateri4, testMateri5, testMateri6 ]);
```

Comment: Sadly, no. The `.envMap` property only accepts a `CubeTexture`, it was not built to handle an array of 6 materials because you cannot add a material into another material: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMap